# Change a data of a class passed as parameter inside React Hooks useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I would like to ask what would be the origin of using classes inside useState, I didn't see a certain "Disapproval" anywhere, but at the same time I don't see anyone using it, so would passing classes be plausible?

In the development of my software, I determined that it would work well, at least for read-only, but the direction of the project changes and now I need me to change an attribute of a class, which is within another class - It seems that React reloads the page but it doesn't change the value of my attribute, I made a small example without typescript for didactic purposes:

```
import React from "react";

class Foo {
  constructor(fooText, bar) {
    this.fooText = fooText;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
  fooText;
  bar;
}

class Bar {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
  data;
}

export default function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState(
    new Foo("Foo text!", new Bar("Look this data!"))
  );

  async function changeFoo() {
    //await TODO Change data on database
    console.log("Refreshing!");
    foo.bar.data = "Now bar have another data!!";
    foo.fooText = "Updated foo text!";
    console.log(foo);
    //PROBABLY THE PROBLEM IS HERE, 
    setFoo(foo);
  }

  console.log("Page re-rendering!");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{foo.fooText}</h1>
      <h1 onClick={changeFoo}>{foo.bar.data}</h1>;
    </div>
  );
}
```

changing the entire class architecture to an object and using it in useState would be very difficult, I would like to avoid this solution, but I think about doing it - if I have no other option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with classes, is that they are (typically) mutable, but state needs to be immutable.

---

React detects new state by testing to see if the old state is strictly equal (`===` operator) to the new state. That means that two variables that reference the same instance of your class are considered equal. And when you change the data in an instance of the class, you are mutating that instance. This means that React will not notice that the state has actually changed, and will not re-render to show that new state.

You could use classes in your state, but you need to design those classes to be immutable. That means that whenever a value in the class would change, it calls a method that returns a *new* instance of the class with that change.

```
class Bar {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  setData(data) {
     return new Bar(data)
  }
}
```

Now you could `setBar(bar.setData(newData))`, and a new instance would be saved to the `bar` state, and then a re-render would be triggered.

---

That's a pain though, and it's much easier to do this with plain objects and the `...` spread operator.  I, and I imagine most other React devs, would definitely recommend switching away from using classes this way.

Comment: It has the same behavior as using the Bloc pattern `===` in the flutter / dart when updating the state
I had a little suspicion of this, but I would not have reached this conclusion without you, I am now recreating the class now with each update - And from now on I will program using only objects and primitive types
Thanks, Alex!

Answer (score 2):

`useState`, as you're using it, will construct that class during every render, which can be bad for performance. You can provide a constructor to `useState` that will only run once, like so:

```
const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState(() => {
    new Foo("Foo text!", new Bar("Look this data!"))
  });
```

However, changing properties on the class will not cause a rerender, like you might expect. Instead, you'll need to replace your instance of the class entirely via `setFoo`.

For those reasons this is a bit of an anti-pattern and should be avoided.

Comment: The performance leak makes sense, I appreciate your good intention, but this example was created in a hurry and does not show up in my production project - But now that I know I will avoid passing classes directly on useState